# Is there a constant for "__main__"?

Tags: python

It [seems](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) that every Python executable file should use this typical pattern:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Is there a constant for `"__main__"`, so that I could use the following rather than hardcoding the string:

```
if __name__ == PYTHON_MAIN_FUNC:
```

Comment: `__name__` etc. are special. Look up "dunder"/magic methods/double underline in Python. What it does here is: When you run a python file e.g. `python myprogram.py` the variable `__name__` of `myprogram.py` will be set to the string `"__main__"`. This allows you to setup special functionality for it. Usually you put in here how your program is executed. 
If you have another python file and execute that and import `myprogram.py` the variable `__main__` will have a different value and thus no longer execute the code within that.

Comment: If you just `print(__name__)` in a console, it'll return`'__main__'`, it's not so much a constant value in the way you're thinking, but rather a "special name".

Comment: This might be the exception that confirms the rule. There is no problem in using a hardcoded string there. However, if it bothers you, noone is stopping you from defining your own constant: `PYTHON_MAIN_FUNC = "__main__"`

Comment: Standard practice is to use `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Even if you found a constant somewhere, using it would confuse people who had to read or maintain your code. (That's not an ideal state of affairs, but it's how things are.)

Comment: The thing that separates this from other cases where it is considered bad practice to hardcode a string is: `if __name__ == "__main__":` really makes sense to exist only once in a module. Because of that, using a constant name will not protect you from things like a typo, because you still have to define that constant.

Comment: @matszwecja: That's an argument against defining the constant in the module where you use it, but if the standard library provided a named constant for this string, that issue wouldn't occur.

Comment: @user2357112 fair enough.

Comment: There's less potential for a typo when using `__main__` since if you mistype it somehow your whole file won't run and you'll notice immediately.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not aware of the standard library providing anything like `PYTHON_MAIN_FUNC`, you could make use of `import __main__`[[Doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#import-main):

```
import __main__

if __name__ == __main__.__name__:
    ...
```

It is available everywhere, it always imports the `__main__.py` of the top-level scope [[Doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#import-main) (Except for the top level `__main__.py`, where it imports something else. See [[Doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#import-main) on how it avoids circular imports).

However, I recommend the "idiomatic" way of writing `__name__ == "__main__"`, as:

- The standard library uses it
- It is well established outside the standard library (So most developers can immediately read and understand it)
- Bugs are unlikely to be introduced and go by unrecognized when mistyped
- Its arguably not the intended use of `__name__` part of a module? (Although that might be fine, since its compared to the `__name__` of the current module)